# Sort in MYSQL PHP date

Tags: php, mysql

```
$mydate = date('H:i, j F Y');
11:51, 11 November 2016
```

What is wrong here?

```
SELECT id, mydate, DATE(mydate) AS DATE2 FROM myTable ORDER BY DATE2 DESC LIMIT 5
```

Its showing me like this:

```
11:41, 10 November 2016
20:17, 4 November 2016
22:49, 9 November 2016
21:04, 9 November 2016
21:32, 3 November 2016
```

Comment: Could you show the exact output of your SQL query ?

Comment: 10 November then 4 November ?

Comment: I think what @TimBiegeleisen means is that the format is good, not the order. Again, could you show the SQL output, that way we can determine what's wrong in the order ?

Comment: Try this - `SELECT id, mydate, DATE(mydate) AS DATE2 FROM myTable ORDER BY mydate DESC LIMIT 5`